# Update encrypted column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I have two encrypted columns in SQL Server 2016 and I would like to update the values of these 2 columns.

I read on the [Microsoft Always Encrypted page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx) that to be able to update an encrypted colum, it "*requires at least SQL Server Management Studio version 17 to insert, update, or filter encrypted columns*." So I looked at SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), the current release for production use is v16.5.3. The only v17 I can see is 17.0 RC3 and it has a comment saying "*not recommended for production use*". Our Operation team is not very willing to use this version since it is not recommended. Our C# code can make changes to these columns, but it is not an easy process to update production source code and we simply want to fix some data in these encrypted columns.

So the question is without SSMS version 17, is there a way to update SQL erver 2016 Encrypted Columns in SSMS?

Comment: Update: SSMS v17.0 has released. You should now be able to update encrypted cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: SSMS v17.0 has released. You should now be able to update encrypted cells.

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is no. Currently only SSMS v17 release candidates support updating cells encrypted using Always Encrypted.